# Distinguish file creation from file open

Tags: c, windows, minifilter

Although not the end goal, the best way of describing what I'm doing is tracking file creations like Sysinternals Sysmon does. I copied the nullfilter sample from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/main/filesys/miniFilter/nullFilter/nullFilter.c) and made adjustments. The following code is truncated to show only changes to the sample:

nullfilter.c

```
// ...
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
FLTAPI CheckPathLengthPost(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
);
// ...

CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION callback[] =
{
    {
        IRP_MJ_CREATE,
        0,
        CheckPathLengthPre,
        CheckPathLengthPost
    },

    {IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END}
};

CONST FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {

    sizeof( FLT_REGISTRATION ),         //  Size
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,           //  Version
    0,                                  //  Flags

    NULL,                               //  Context
    callback,                           //  Operation callbacks

    NullUnload,                         //  FilterUnload

    NULL,                               //  InstanceSetup
    NullQueryTeardown,                  //  InstanceQueryTeardown
    NULL,                               //  InstanceTeardownStart
    NULL,                               //  InstanceTeardownComplete

    NULL,                               //  GenerateFileName
    NULL,                               //  GenerateDestinationFileName
    NULL                                //  NormalizeNameComponent

};
// ...
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
FLTAPI CheckPathLengthPre(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext
)
{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);

    if (Data->RequestorMode == KernelMode)
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;

    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION info = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_OPENED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT | FLT_FILE_NAME_DO_NOT_CACHE, &info);
    if (!(NT_SUCCESS(status))) {
        DbgPrint("nullfilter|CheckPathLengthPre: FltGetFileNameInformation failed: %#x", status);
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    ULONG createDisp = (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24) & 0x000000FF;

    BOOLEAN isCreation = ((createDisp == FILE_CREATE) ||
        (createDisp == FILE_SUPERSEDE) ||
        (createDisp == FILE_OVERWRITE) ||
        (createDisp == FILE_OVERWRITE_IF) ||
        (createDisp == FILE_OPEN_IF));


    // File or folder is being created
    if ((Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options) & FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE) {
        if (isCreation == 1) {
            DbgPrint("nullfilter: isFile: %d, isDir: %d, createDisp: <%08x>, Path: %wZ", 1, 0, createDisp, info->Name);
        }
    }
    else if ((Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options) & FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE) {
        if (isCreation == 1) {
            DbgPrint("nullfilter: isFile: %d, isDir: %d, createDisp: <%08x>, Path: %wZ", 0, 1, createDisp, info->Name);
        }
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}
```

nullfilter.inf

```
[Version]
Signature   = "$Windows NT$"
Class       = "Bottom"             ;This is determined by the work this filter driver does
ClassGuid   = {21D41938-DAA8-4615-86AE-E37344C18BD8}    ;This value is determined by the Class
Provider    = %ProviderString%
DriverVer   = 06/16/2007,1.0.0.0
CatalogFile = nullfilter.cat
; ...
[NullFilter.Service]
DisplayName      = %ServiceName%
Description      = %ServiceDescription%
ServiceBinary    = %12%\%DriverName%.sys    ;%windir%\system32\drivers\
Dependencies     = "FltMgr"
ServiceType      = 2                        ;SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType        = 3                        ;SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl     = 1                        ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
LoadOrderGroup   = "FSFilter Bottom"
AddReg           = NullFilter.AddRegistry
; ...
[Strings]
; ...
DefaultInstance         = "Null Instance"
Instance1.Name          = "Null Instance"
Instance1.Altitude      = "47777"
Instance1.Flags         = 0
```

This was probably the best question I found in terms of providing source: [Minifilter Check new file create on harddisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336334/minifilter-check-new-file-create-on-harddisk)

Issue is that it tracks **opens** and creations. I can't find anything additional to narrow it down. This is the issue with any other discussion I've found on this:

- [minifilter driver | tracking changes in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159942/minifilter-driver-tracking-changes-in-files)
- https://community.osr.com/discussion/283813/file-creation-and-modification-detection-can-a-mini-filter-get-me-there
- [Block file creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957478/block-file-creation)
- [Block file creation in Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627912/block-file-creation-in-windows10)
- [Minifilter prevent new file created with warning dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398552/minifilter-prevent-new-file-created-with-warning-dialog)
- [Can I catch file CREATION the operation in minifilter driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292142/can-i-catch-file-creation-the-operation-in-minifilter-driver)

Most of these are discussion with limited code. They all appear to suggest what I've already tried above. Perhaps I'm in the wrong spot, perhaps at this-low level there is no distinction?

Answer (score 0):

Looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irp-mj-create (again?) and I think I'm onto something.

nullfilter.c

```
// ...
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
FLTAPI CheckPathLengthPost(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
);
// ...
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
FLTAPI CheckPathLengthPre(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext
)
{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);

    if (Data->RequestorMode == KernelMode)
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;

    NTSTATUS status;
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION info = NULL;
    if (NULL != FltObjects->FileObject) {
        status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_OPENED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT | FLT_FILE_NAME_DO_NOT_CACHE, &info);
    }
    else {
        status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }

    if (!(NT_SUCCESS(status))) {
        DbgPrint("nullfilter|CheckPathLengthPre: FltGetFileNameInformation failed: %#x", status);
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
FLTAPI CheckPathLengthPost(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
)
{
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION info;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Flags);

    UINT16 isCreation = ((Data->IoStatus.Information == FILE_CREATED));

    info = (PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION)CompletionContext;
    
    if (isCreation == 1) {
        DbgPrint("nullfilter|CheckPathLengthPost: Path: %wZ\r\n", info->Name);
    }

    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}
```

After thinking about my question, I wondered why again do I believe this "isn't working". *DbgView* was showing far too much activity, certainly thousands of files aren't being created a second. I determined my create disposition was too wide. For this test, I only care about **new** files. Additionally, I added a post-create callback as, I believe, `IOStatus` will not be correct in pre-create.

Since the change, *DbgView* has significantly less output. The files listed are cache or journal files, both of which are definitely new files. Opening files is not treated "incorrectly".